# Home improvement loan for dependent support worksheet

Tags: united-states, social-security, dependents

My mom had to finance HVAC replacement in a condo we purchased together, but she is the permanent resident, as I live in another state. She receives SSD payments.

For the dependency support worksheet, how do we treat the financed amount, which practically is a loan? She pays off the loan with the money I deposit into her account. She also pays other condo expenses with that (my) money.

Comment: I think it is tax related, not SS related. It is about dependent support worksheet for 1040